# Error using dplyr::copy_to() with vertica JDBC connection

Tags: r, jdbc, dplyr, vertica

My attempt to copy a local df to my vertica database is triggering the following error message. I know that the connection is working because my other queries work. But I am unsure of how to start trouble shooting this error:

```
dplyr::copy_to(
    dest = conn,
    df = mtcars
)
```

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbBegin’ for signature ‘"JDBCConnection"’